# Rails: complex HABTM relationship with 3 keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to determine how many meeting hours a particular Organization has, but it's not as easy as it seems it should be because of certain relationship complexities.

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :people
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_any_belongs_to_many :meetings
    has_and_belongs_to_many :positions
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :people  # b/c over time more than one person
                        may hold this position over time
    belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :positions
end
```

Because People may change positions (and Organizations) over time, when someone attends a meeting, I need to also make note of their position at that time in order for the tally to be accurate.

As it currently stands, because the HATBM join table is handled implicitly (meetings_people), I can't track position.  How do I add position into this mix and what's the best way to write the query to get the total meeting hours for each organization?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :through` allows you use to use a proper join model, instead of an implied on like `habtm`. You would make a whole class called something like `MeetingAttendance`, where you would store the meeting and who attended. Then you can put whatever attributes on the model you want, including `position`. Then simply

```
Person has_many :meeting_attendances
Person has_many :meetings, :through => :meeting_attendances
Meeting has_many :meeting_attendances
Meeting has_many :people, :through => :meeting_attendances
```

and

```
class MeetingAttendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :meeting
end
```

Note: You may need to tweak that as I'm not sure how Rails handles the pluralization of "Person", but this is the general idea.

[Documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)